# How to call shell command via VAPI-XP-TEST

Tags: hp-quality-center

I have .py script that run from the cmd.
I want to execute it in quality center automatically (I understood that is done using the test type VAPI-XP-TEST) and to get indication of '"Pass"/"Fail".
How exactly I can do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link: http://alm-help.saas.hpe.com/en/12.50/online_help/Content/UG/t_create_vapixp_scripts.htm

Also, VAPI-XP allows Python script. I have not used Python for VAPI-XP yet, but HP documentation in the above link I believe can help you get up to speed.